# Django - What is better, creating a ImageField on DB or a string path?

Tags: python, django

i started programming on Django and needed to make an Image Upload, saving the imagepath.
I have 2 options, save the image on the BD as an ImageField or Save the path where the image is saved. Which one is better?

Comment: ImageField does not save image in database but its path https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/files/#managing-files

Answer (score -1):

Use the way django suggests: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ImageField. One of the perks of django is that many things work out of the box. Leverage that!

Comment: thanks, but i saved my path and stored the image on S3